# .NET handling of tiff files corrupts on XP, but not Win7

Tags: .net, tiff

I need to read some tiff files into a WPF, and I had it all working nicely, until I tested it on Windows XP.  The image that's loaded appears to be corrupted, regardless of how I load it.

Attached are 2 screenshots of the same program loading the same image - the dark one is how it should look (loaded from Win7), the other is how it looks when loaded in XP.

I've tried loading as a BitmapImage, a BitmapSource, loading a FileStream and passing to a BitmapImage, directly from an Image tag in WPF... all have the same sort of corruption.  I've used the .NET LibTiff library to get around the problem, but it doesn't explain why it happens, and I'm at a bit of a loss to explain it!

Edit:  I should add that the image is 16 bit.

[image: Loaded in Windows 7][image: Loaded in XP]

Comment: Pretty typical for the kind of raw images that satellites transmit.  Check the wiring of your machine.  Expecting us to diagnose coding bugs from satellite images isn't going to get you a great answer.  Post the code and a link to the image file.

Comment: Both the above images are loaded from a tiff - there's no external equipment involved - it's the same file.  The only difference is the lower one is a screenshot of the image as loaded in XP, and the top on is a screenshot as Windows 7 - both using the same program.  I used various methods of loading it, and they all produced this error.

Comment: TIFF is notorious for this. It's a really badly supported format.

Comment: Try upgrading the Windows Imaging Component on XP.

Comment: @ David, glad it's not just me!

Comment: @ Anton - I've installed the .NET 4 framework, and trying to install the WIC from MSDN site tells me there's a newer version installed.

Comment: @zotty: if you must use WPF to process these images, consider upgrading to Vista or Windows 7. Otherwise consdier using LibTiff. (or... Fedora) @Anton: Since the mainstream support for Windows XP has expired, the Windows Imaging Component on XP would no longer be updated with enhancements [such as this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support from Windows for the TIFF format is very poor in XP and greatly enhanced in Windows 7. 16 bit is not supported by the XP (that is, it only uses 8 bit)
Please have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee720061%28VS.85%29.aspx to see what is improved in Windows 7. You can also see it as a list of bugs and limitations fixed in W7, and present in Windows XP....

When using LibTiff (or LibTiff.NET), you won't be using the windows imaging class, other than to display a resulting bitmap.
I did some range mapping (16->8 bit) my self, using AForge.NET  to visualize. I did this by implementing a function which would translate a tile from my tiff file (16 bit) into a 8 bit BMP, including image enancement (i.e. leveling)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an external library like [LibTiff](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/)?

Comment: I have - LibTiff works perfectly, but I was curious as to why there's a difference between the same program each using the same program.  I thought the point of .NET was that so long as you install the framework you should be able to run any program.

Comment: I agree that it "should" work that way, but I also know that the tiff handling of .Net leaves a lot to be desired. I also have no clue as to why it doesn't behave the same on different machines. Too bad we can't debug the internals in an easy fashion.

Comment: @zotty: that is because .NET Framework depends on some "platform components", which are services tied to a particular version/edition of Windows. The Windows Imaging Component is an example of a platform component. Thus, even though the .NET Framework code is the same, the platform component acted differently on different OS versions/editions (XP vs Vista vs Win 7).